# PHP string switch using NOT operator

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a small switch statement in the header of a portfolio website I'm working on which governs which links are shown on which page. The value of $id comes from the GET variable, ie - '?id=index'.

```
    switch($id) {
    case "index":
        //Show links to content
    case !"index":
        //Show link to index
    case !"about":
        //show link to about page
}
```

The issue is that the NOT operator isn't working in the final two cases. I want the link to the index to show when the user is NOT on the index page, and likewise with the about page. Currently, ALL links are shown on the index page (when $id == "index), and NONE are shown on any other pages.

Why might this be?

Comment: no switch case doesn't work this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so, because it is supposed to be so.

`switch` compares using the `==` operator. So in the second case, you are actually testing whether

```
$id == (!"index")
```

Which will always evaluate to `false` since any string would be `true`and not true would be `false`.

Which means, in your case it would be better to use `if` and `else`.

Comment: I'm still quite new to programming, what specifically is the difference between $id == !"index" and $id != "index" ?

Comment: `$id != "index"` tests whether `$id` is *not equal* to `"index"`. `$id == !"index"` tests whether the negation of `"index"` (whatever that may be) is equal to `$id`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but what you're trying to do is simply not valid syntax for a `switch` / `case` construct.

The closest you'll come to what you're looking for is to use the `default` option. This works like a final `case` option, that deals with all values that were not caught by any of the preceding `case`s.

```
switch($id) {
    case "index":
        //Show links to content
    case "about":
        //Show link to about page
    default:
        //show link to default page.
}
```

Also - don't forget the `break;` at the end of each `case` block, otherwise it'll fall through to the next one, which can lead to some unexpected bugs.

Answer (score 0):

`!"index"` will probably evaluate as `false` (but I'm little surprised it didn't cause syntax error) and you'll actually having this statement:

```
switch($id){
    case "index": //...
    case false: // ...
    case false: // ...
}
```

When you want to use `switch`, you'll need to do is this way:

```
switch($id){
    case "index": // ...
    case "about": // ...
    default: 
        // Additional statements here, note that $id != "index" is already covered 
        // by not entering into case "index"
}
```

Comment: This is because `switch` cases in PHP are expressions, not scalar values.  Even something like `case (substr($foo, -2) . "bar"):` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The switch case does not accept complex expressions. The not ! operator is a **logical** operator. It works in expressions like this.

```
!$x; // true if $x = false
```

or as a **comparison** operator:

```
 $a != $b; // Not equal
 // or 
 $a !== $b // not identical
```

From the manual.

> The case expression of the [switch](http://no.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement may be any expression
>   that evaluates to a simple type, that is, integer or floating-point
>   numbers and strings. Arrays or objects cannot be used here unless they
>   are dereferenced to a simple type.

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is comparing $id against three values: "index", !"index" (whatever it means) and !"about".

I'm not sure about your approach. You should try if/else or ternary operators.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Switch doesn't offer custom operators.

```
 switch ( $id ) {
     case 'index':
          // $id == 'index'

          break;

     case 'about':
          // $id == 'about'

          break;

     case 'help':
     case 'info':
           // $id == 'info' or $id == 'help'

           break;

     default:
          // all other cases
}
```

Answer (score 0):

surely you can fix this with:

```
switch($id){
    case ($id != 'index'):
        echo 'this is not index';
        break;
    case 'index':
        echo 'this is index';
        break;
    case 'foo':
        echo 'this is foo!';
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

However, this example is flawed, because the first case statement will just catch anything that isn't 'index' thus you shouldn't ever get to the case 'foo' nor the default statement